# Darknet: How labels used for classification?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, classification, darknet

I want to use YOLOv3 for classification without bbox detection, and am following this link [how to train a classifier with darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/train-cifar/)

However, I can't seem to spot where exactly the class for each image is assigned. There isn't any `.txt` file for each image like for detection. Is the class simply extracted from the file name?

How do I assign a class to each image in my multi-class classification? Or do I simply throw in the images and YOLO learns by itself based on the number of classes you specify in `labels.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the class of each training images is extracted from the file name. Check out the `load_labels_path()` and `fill_truth()` functions in `src/data.c`. `load_labels_path()` creates a `# of images` by `# of classes` matrix, and fill it with 1 and 0 whether the image belong to the class using `fill_truth()`, which tests whether a class name is a substring of a image file name.

```c
matrix load_labels_paths(char **paths, int n, char **labels, int k, tree *hierarchy)
{
    matrix y = make_matrix(n, k);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n && labels; ++i){
        fill_truth(paths[i], labels, k, y.vals[i]);
        if(hierarchy){
            fill_hierarchy(y.vals[i], k, hierarchy);
        }
    }
    return y;
}

...

void fill_truth(char *path, char **labels, int k, float *truth)
{
    int i;
    memset(truth, 0, k*sizeof(float));
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < k; ++i){
        if(strstr(path, labels[i])){
            truth[i] = 1;
            ++count;
            //printf("%s %s %d\n", path, labels[i], i);
        }
    }
    if(count != 1 && (k != 1 || count != 0)) printf("Too many or too few labels: %d, %s\n", count, path);
}
```

https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/src/data.c#L620
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/src/data.c#L543